# Singleton with dynamic variable

Tags: java

I need to call function to recalculate argument from different place of program {different classes}. I need to recalculate with different coefficient which can be changed in running time.
Simple example: new_value = old_value * coefficient.

At the moment I have class which hold those coefficient and has methods which are doing that recalculation. Disadvantage: I need to pass that instance of class to each place where I want to used it.

This is my singleton:

```
public class Converter {
    private double              lbU_2_U;
    private static Converter    instance    = new Converter();

    public Converter() {
        lbU_2_U = 1;
    }

    public static Converter getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void updateVelocityCoeficient(double lb_2_p) {
        lbU_2_U = lb_2_p;
    }

    public double velToP(double lbU) {
        return lbU_2_U * lbU;
    }

    public double velToLB(double u) {
        return u / lbU_2_U;
    }
}
```

so, advantage now will be that in anywhere in program I can write

```
newVelocity = Converter.getInstance().velToP(velocity)
```

Go for forward, I would do something like this:

```
newVelocity = Converter.velToP(velocity)
```

so I am thinking about change my Singleton to this:

```
public class Converter {
    private double              lbU_2_U;
    private static Converter    instance    = new Converter();

    public Converter() {
        lbU_2_U = 1;
    }

    public static Converter getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static void updateVelocityCoeficient(double lb_2_p) {
        instance.lbU_2_U = lb_2_p;
    }

    public static double velToP(double lbU) {
        return instance.lbU_2_U * lbU;
    }

    public static double velToLB(double u) {
        return u / instance.lbU_2_U;
    }
}
```

What do you thing?
I am not sure if this is effective, if I can used this in multipleThread app, and if this is correct way of using Singleton.

thank you

Comment: Those identifiers (variable/method names) are cryptic. Please use more descriptive identifiers

Comment: Singleton is one concept, not a formal specification. Better is to understand concepts. see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228164/on-design-patterns-when-to-use-the-singleton

Comment: @elif He has a programming problem (cannot achieve dynamic nature), so I don't think it would be proper for CodeReview

Comment: Stateful singletons are a bad idea. See [Why is Global State so Evil?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)

Comment: This is not really a singleton; I would recommend to make your constructor private.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good scenario to use the Singleton pattern.

Have a look into these answers: [When should the Singleton pattern NOT be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074154/when-should-the-singleton-pattern-not-be-used-besides-the-obvious)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this to be a `Singleton` - all you need is some `static` methods.

```
public class Converter {

    private static double lbU_2_U = 1;

    private Converter() {
        // No non-static methods so disallow construction.
    }

    public static void updateVelocityCoeficient(double lb_2_p) {
        lbU_2_U = lb_2_p;
    }

    public static double velToP(double lbU) {
        return lbU_2_U * lbU;
    }

    public static double velToLB(double u) {
        return u / lbU_2_U;
    }
}
```

I will not go into the discussion here on whether you are using a good or bad pattern here.

Answer (score 0):

That's Nice. But :

-Your constructor should be private to be a Singleton. (you are the only able to create an instance)

```
private Converter() {
    lbU_2_U = 1;
}
```

-I dont believe you need to use a singleton. You only need a

```
private static double lbU_2_U;
```

Comment: 1) yes, constructor will be private, quick writing 2) well, I need to change that lbU_2_P coefficient in running program

Comment: you can change static attributes while running. "public void setlbU_2_P(double d)"